# Transport equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have the following PDE.
$$
yu_x - 2xyu_y = 2xu, \quad u(0,y) = y^3
$$

The way I went about is as followed, however I feel that somewhere I make a mistake. Could someone please clarify where exactly I go wrong (I believe it's at the start wherein I make the assumption that $x=s$).

[image]

Comment: Seems correct to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you thinking that you made a mistake ?. Your result is exact.

Nevertheless there is a slightly simpler way :

The system of characteristic differential equation is :
$$\frac{dx}{y}=\frac{dy}{-2xy}=\frac{du}{2xu}$$
A first equation of characteristic comes from : $\frac{dx}{y}=\frac{dy}{-2xy}$
$$-2xdx=dy \quad\to\quad y+x^2=c_1$$
A second equation of characteristic comes from : $\frac{dy}{-2xy}=\frac{du}{2xu}$
$$-\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{du}{u} \quad\to\quad yu=c_2$$
The general solution on the form of implicit equation is :
$$F(y+x^2,yu)=0$$
Where $F$ is any differentiable function of two variables. This is equivalent to :
$$yu=f(y+x^2) \quad\to\quad u(x,y)=\frac{1}{y}f(y+x^2)$$
where $f$ is any differentiable function.

The condition $u(0,y)=y^3$ implies :
$$\frac{1}{y}f(y+0)=y^3 \quad\to\quad f(t)=t^4$$
We use the dummy variable $t$ in order to not confuse the case $t=y$ if $x=0$ with the case $t=y+x^2$ if $x\neq 0$. Hence, the solution according to the boundary condition is :
$$u(x,y)=\frac{1}{y}(y+x^2)^4$$

Comment: I've never seen this form before. How exactly do you justify that $F(y+x^2,yu) = 0$ is equivalent to $yu = f(y+x^2)$ ?

Comment: Consider the equation $F(X,Y)=0$ . Solving it for $Y$ leads to $Y=f(X)$. If $F$ is any function, then $f$ is any function. Note that $f$ can be a multi-valuated function, since it is any function.